# Trouble getting ListView to re-render

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to force a ListView to rerender, only the changed rows.
The documentation suggests `rowHasChanged` function. I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.
here's the redacted code for reference, which doesn't work for me:

```js
'use strict'

import React from 'react-native';
import {
  ListView,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Component
}
from 'react-native';


export default class Follows extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      apiData: [],
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1.id !== row2.id || row1.following !== row2.following
      })
    };
  }

  _fetchData() {
    fetch(some_url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.state.apiData = responseData.data;
        this.setState({
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.apiData),
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        callOnFetchError(error, some_url);
      }).done();
  })
}

componentDidMount() {
  this._fetchData()
}

_follow(id, shouldFollow) {
  const refreshedData = this.state.apiData.map(user => {
    if (user.id === id)
      user.following = shouldFollow ? 1 : 0;
    return user;
  })
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(refreshedData),
  })
}

_renderRow() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress = {this._follow.bind(this, 37, true}>
               
              /* some view */
        </TouchableOpacity>
 )
}

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          style={styles.listView}
          dataSource={ this.state.dataSource }
          renderRow={this._renderRow()}
        </ListView >
        < /View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below setup. There are two things I think that are making the functionality not work for you:

1 - The way you are referring to your dataSource as this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows. Instead, try setting a variable like below:

```
var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
```

Then using it like this:

```
this.setState({
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseData.data),
});
```

2 - Instead of this:

```
this.state.apiData = responseData.data;
```

Try this:

```
this.setState({
  apiData: responseData.data
})
```

Overall, I've changed the original code to the below, which I think should work:

```js
'use strict'

import React from 'react-native';
import {
  ListView,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Component
}
from 'react-native';

var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

export default class Follows extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      apiData: [],
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([])
    };
  }

  _fetchData() {
    fetch(some_url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          apiData: responseData.data,
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseData.data),
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        callOnFetchError(error, some_url);
      }).done();
  })
}

componentDidMount() {
  this._fetchData()
}

_follow(id, shouldFollow) {
  const refreshedData = this.state.apiData.map(user => {
    if (user.id === id)
      user.following = shouldFollow ? 1 : 0;
    return user;
  })
  this.setState({
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(refreshedData),
  })
}

_renderRow() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress = {this._follow.bind(this, 37, true}>
               
              /* some view */
        </TouchableOpacity>
 )
}

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          style={styles.listView}
          dataSource={ this.state.dataSource }
          renderRow={this._renderRow()}
        </ListView >
        < /View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: That was kinda silly of me to not see that happening. :) Thanks! It works now.